# Extract words from text and create a vector from them

Tags: r, regex, gsub, text-processing, stringr

Suppose, I have a txt file that contains such text:

```
Type: fruits
Title: retail
Date: 2015-11-10
Country: UK
Products:
  apple,
  passion fruit,
  mango
Documents: NDA
Export: 2.10
```

I read this file with `readLines` function. 
Then, I want to get a vector that looks like this:

```
x <- c(fruits, apple, passion fruit, mango)
```

So, I want to extract the word after "Type:" and all words between "Products:" and  "Documents:". 
How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a more elegant solution, in case you can try this, if you got a vector like this:

```
vec <- readLines("path\\file.txt")
```

And in the file there is the text you posted, you can try this:

```
# replace biggest spaces
gsub("   "," ",
     # replace the first space
     sub(" ",", ",
       # pattern to extract words
       gsub(".*Type:\\s*|Title.*Products:\\s*| Documents.*", "",
           # collapse in one vector
           paste0(vec, collapse = " "))))
[1] "fruits, apple, passion fruit, mango"
```

---

If you `dput(vec)` to make code reproducible:

```
c("Type: fruits", "Title: retail", "Date: 2015-11-10", "Country: UK", 
"Products:", "  apple,", "  passion fruit,", "  mango", "Documents: NDA", 
"Export: 2.10")
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's not subject to change, it looks close to `yaml` format e.g. using package of the same name

```
library(yaml)
info <- yaml::read_yaml("your file.txt")
# strsplit - split either side of the commas
# unlist - convert to vector
# trimws - remove trailing and leading white space
out <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(info$Products, ",")))
```

You will get the other entries as list elements in `info` of the required name e.g. `info$Type`